Git repository forked from svn upstream. Now upstream moved to git. How to relate history?
I have a project in github. It's a repository which is built upon (fork) another repository (upstream) which uses svn for source control. I created it with the following steps:

I initialized a new empty git repo (my fork).
I pulled the svn commits from upstream using git svn. This was done in branch svn.
I created a master branch from the svn branch and applied my code changes.
When the svn repo was updated, I was able to pull the new commits from svn using git svn. This was done in the svn branch of my repo.
Then any changed were merged into my master branch without any issue.

This worked ok, for a long time, and many git svn pulls and merge commits have been made.
Now, the upstream svn repo has been moved to git as well. The migration to git was done directly from the svn repo using git svn. As a result the new git repo of the upstream repo has completely different commit hashes (history) from the git svn commit hashes my repo has.
How do I keep on pulling from the upstream repo to my fork? I tried adding the upstream git repo as remote upstream but merging its new commits to my fork failed because of unrelated histories.
Is setting the –allow-unrelated-histories option the proper way to do it? If yes, do I have to use it on every merge from the upstream, or only on the first merge?
Is there other ways to deal with this? Thanks.
